# Creating multiple parameter callback function for UWA.Data.getJson

Tags: javascript, widget

I'm using the [NetVibes UWA widget framework](http://dev.netvibes.com/doc/uwa/documentation/using_ajax).

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters to my callback function, which right now, looks like this:

```
UWA.Data.getJson(List.URL + '?cmd=getCoursesFromSubjects&faculty=' + subject, List.tickCheckboxes);
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
var checked = ('#input').attr("checked");
UWA.Data.getJson(List.URL + '?cmd=getCoursesFromSubjects&faculty=' + subject, List.tickCheckboxes(data,checked));
```

But that doesn't work. I've looked at other answers and tried "closure" techniques, but then my `data` comes back as `null`.

Is this a limitation of the UWA format or am I just doing the closures wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, worked it out. Was doing my closure wrong.

```
UWA.Data.getJson(List.URL + '?cmd=getSubjectsFromFaculties&faculty=' + faculty, (function(thischecked) {
                  return function(data) {
                     List.tickCheckboxes(data, thischecked);
                  };
               }(checked))
            );
```